# Filtering on a model's calculated method using django_filter

Tags: django, methods, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I have a Django model with a calculated field on it.  As an example:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField(default=3)

    @property
    def incremented(self):
        return self.number + 1
```

I'd like to filter on this property, so I tried the following:

```
class ModelFilter(django_filter.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('incremented',)
```

That did not work, and neither did this:

```
class ModelFilter(django_filter.FilterSet):
    incremented = django_filter.NumberFilter(lookup_type='exact')
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('incremented',)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`incremented` is not a field (i.e an instance of [`Field`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field)) on that model, it is just a python function.  On the database side of things, it doesn't exist, so can't be filtered on.

Until [#14030](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14030) is fixed, you can't filter on calculated values like this easily, you have to use [`extra`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra).  So for example to get all objects with `number` of 2 via `incremented`:

```
MyModel.objects.extra(where=['number + 1 = %s'], params=[3])
```

To use that with the `django-filter` library, you'll need to override the `action` of your `Filter`:

```
def action(query, value):
    return query.extra(where=['number + 1 = %s'], params=[value])

class F(django_filters.FilterSet):
    incremented = django_filters.NumberFilter(action=action)
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['incremented']
```

Comment: Thanks.  I think this `action` kwarg was exactly what I was looking for--didn't see it in the docs.

Comment: Is this #14030 now fixed?